# Have a class method hold a different static variable for every instance

Tags: c++

So my problem is this:

I have a class containing an int `position`, and a method that moves the instance by a float `move(float dx)`. However, I keep the remainder and move the instance from the integer part of `dx`. It is implemented this way (this is only a minimal example):

```cpp
#include <algorithm>

class A {
  public:
    A(x): position(x) {}

    void move(float dx) {
        static float remainder{0.f};

        float total_dx = dx + remainder;
        int to_move = std::floor(total_dx);

        position += to_move;
        remainder = total_dx - to_move;
    }

  private:
    int position;
};
```

My problem is that every instance of `A` shares `remainder`. This variable is only used by the method `move`, so it feels unnatural (and bad) to put it in the class as a private member. I was wondering if there was a way to limit the variable to the scope of `move` while having every instance of `A` hold its unique `remainder`.

Thank you!

Comment: Have you considered having `remainder` be a class data member, like position? It describes something about each `A` so it should be part of it's state.

Comment: And another private data member, the remainder.

Comment: If a variable helps an instance fulfill its function, even in a single method, well...

Comment: Yes, as I said, my real class `A` is pretty big, and it feels a bit... unnatural to have `remainder` in it's members since it is EXCLUSIVELY used by `move`. If that's the only way, I guess I'll have to stick to this, but my question is exactly this: is it avoidable?

Comment: We have this already, they are called member variables.  Those are unique per instance.  If you need to publicly available, just make it public.

Comment: @Tommy-XavierRobillard Conceptually, `remainder` is part of what describes a given `A` completely. It's natural and normal that `remainder` be a member of `A`. Even trying to avoid growing `A` won't work. You have to store the information *somewhere*. That's 1 `float` per `A` whether it's a member or not. Maybe you could gather all the `remainder`s somewhere else, but you're just moving storage from one place to another for no gain but at the cost of complexity. `A` has a member `remainder` here.

Comment: In that case I guess I will have to stick to having `remainder` (probably with a more explicit name) as a member. Thank you for the answer!

Comment: It sounds like the root problem here is that your class is already too big.  Maybe the right solution is to refactor your class into multiple smaller classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Have a class method hold a different static variable for every instance

```
void move(float dx) {
    static std::map<A*, float> remainder;

    float total_dx = dx + (remainder.count(this) ? remainder[this] : 0.f);
    int to_move = std::floor(total_dx);

    position += to_move;
    remainder[this] = total_dx - to_move;
}
```

This is what you can do if you want to decouple `remainder` from the class A and limit its access to only `move()` function. However note that objects' addresses may change if kept in dynamic containers or be re-assigned to new objects (if old one was since deleted). If your application poses this risk some unique `id` should be assigned in the constructor but then you end up with `id` member instead of `remainder` member, which seems pointless.

Comment: Thanks! That's exactly what I was looking for. After the discussion I had in the comments, I do think however that just holding `remainder` will be simpler and cleaner. The map would probably just make everything more complex, add memory leaks, and give almost nothing back. It could be useful somewhere else though, so noted!

Comment: I hope those objects don't get created and destroyed often. Because nothing vacates this map that will just keep growing. And I certainly hope no `A` is ever created in the exact same storage another `A` previously occupied.

Comment: @StoryTeller Yea, this is something I warned against in my answer. Regarding growing you're right, not suitable for such app design. Thank you.